# How can I monitor and stress-test an overclocked Ubuntu system?

Tags: 16.04, performance, intel, temperature, overclocking

How would I go about stressing and monitoring temps of my Intel Core i7-4790k on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend stress-ng (since I wrote it to stress test systems), it has a wide range of stress tests built into it. The matrix stressor is a good one to start with as it exercises cpu floating point, cache and memory, for example:

```
stress-ng --matrix 0 -t 60s --tz
stress-ng: info:  [10514] dispatching hogs: 4 matrix
stress-ng: info:  [10514] cache allocate: default cache size: 3072K
stress-ng: info:  [10514] successful run completed in 60.00s (1 min, 0.00 secs)
stress-ng: info:  [10514] matrix:
stress-ng: info:  [10514]               acpitz   78.00 °C
stress-ng: info:  [10514]         x86_pkg_temp   78.25 °C
```

the above runs the matrix stressor on all cpus for 60 seconds and dumps out the thermal zone temperatures for the ACPI thermal zone and the cpu package temperature.

The cpu stressor also contains a wide range of stress methods, for example, to stress the CPU exercising long double floating point operations on 2 CPUs for 30 seconds use the following:

```
stress-ng --cpu 2 --cpu-method longdouble  -t 30s --tz --metrics-brief
stress-ng: info:  [10572] dispatching hogs: 2 cpu
stress-ng: info:  [10572] cache allocate: default cache size: 3072K
stress-ng: info:  [10572] successful run completed in 30.00s
stress-ng: info:  [10572] stressor       bogo ops real time  usr time  sys time   bogo ops/s   bogo ops/s
stress-ng: info:  [10572]                           (secs)    (secs)    (secs)   (real time) (usr+sys time)
stress-ng: info:  [10572] cpu               71482     30.00     59.96      0.00      2382.65      1192.16
stress-ng: info:  [10572] cpu:
stress-ng: info:  [10572]               acpitz   76.00 °C
stress-ng: info:  [10572]         x86_pkg_temp   76.50 °C
```

To see all the cpu stressor methods, use:

```
stress-ng --cpu-method which
cpu-method must be one of: all ackermann bitops callfunc cdouble cfloat
clongdouble correlate crc16 decimal32 decimal64 decimal128 dither djb2a
double euler explog fft fibonacci float fnv1a gamma gcd gray hamming hanoi
hyperbolic idct int128 int64 int32 int16 int8 int128float int128double
int128longdouble int128decimal32 int128decimal64 int128decimal128
int64float int64double int64longdouble int32float int32double
int32longdouble jenkin jmp ln2 longdouble loop matrixprod nsqrt
omega parity phi pi pjw prime psi queens rand rand48 rgb sdbm sieve
sqrt trig union zeta
```

Consult the man page for stress-ng; it has many options for stress testing. See also the [stress-ng project page.](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/stress-ng/)